# How to find out the currently logged-in user in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In [this Spring Boot application](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/blob/master/single/src/main/java/demo/UiApplication.java) there is a web service, which returns some data for a logged-in user:

```
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public Map<String, Object> home() {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    model.put("content", "Hello World");
    return model;
}
```

Imagine, the return value of the method depends on what user is currently logged in.

How can I find out, which user is logged in in that method?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

As per request:

Spring Boot which uses [Spring Security internally](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security) provides a [SecurityContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) class which allows the lookup of the currently authenticated user via:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

The [authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) instance now provides the following methods:

- Get the username of the logged in user: `getPrincipal()`
- Get the password of the authenticated user: `getCredentials()`
- Get the assigned roles of the authenticated user: `getAuthorities()`
- Get further details of the authenticated user: `getDetails()`

Comment: Or easier and less intrusive, simply add a method argument of type `Principal` if you are only interested in the user, or `Authentication` if you want more. Saves you the hassle of working with the `SecurityContextHolder`.

Comment: hello how can i use where should i put this to get the logged user thank you

Comment: @KamelMili As Spring Security usually is a filter hanging right before the actual application logic is entered, you should be able to access the authentication from almost anywhere in your application. Not sure though if this answers your question

Comment: Get the username of the logged in user: getPrincipal() => getName() ?

Comment: Why getCredentials() always return empty string however using auth.eraseCredentials(false)

Comment: Try my answer posted for similar question under https://stackoverflow.com/a/75058792/8294118

Comment: After getting Authentication auth, as shown above, extract user name from principal in such way
((User)auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername()

Answer (score 65):

Since Spring Security 3.2 you can get currently logged in user (your implementation of `UserDetails`) by adding a parameter inside your controller method:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.bind.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;

@RequestMapping("/resource")
public Map<String, Object> home(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
   ..
}
```

Replace `User` with the name of your class which implements `UserDetails` interface.

**Edit**:

Since Spring Security 4.0 annotation was moved to a different package:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
```

**Addendum**:

This will work even in `WebFlux` reactive environment versus the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` which won't work because of paradigm shift from thread per request model to multiple requests per thread.

Comment: This always returns null, even when Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); returns a user

Comment: @DanielMethner That shouldn't happen I'm using this in controllers in Webflux and Non-Webflux environments and it works everywhere. Can you open a new question and post your configuration, spring versions, and controller where it doesn't work and I'll take a look?

Comment: I forgot to send the authentication header. Problem is therefore solved. thanks anyways!

Comment: When I use `@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetailsImpl user` is not null and working. This is for people using a separate class for principal other than `User`

Answer (score 17):

You can simply use HttpServletRequest also to get user principle,

using HttpServletRequest request,

```
String user=request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
```

Answer (score 17):

One way is to add `java.security.Principal` as a parameter as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public Map<String, Object> home(Principal principal) {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    model.put("content", "Hello " + principal.getName());
    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Since version 5.2 you can use [CurrentSecurityContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/annotation/CurrentSecurityContext.html) annotation:

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello(@CurrentSecurityContext(expression="authentication?.name")
                    String username) {
    return "Hello, " + username + "!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Spring boot v2.1.9.RELEASE if you are trying to get the name, `email`, `given_name` you can get those details from `Pricipal`.

Note: I am using spring security with google `oauth2`.

```
Map<String , Object> userDetails = ((DefaultOidcUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getAttributes();
        System.out.println(userDetails.get("name"));
        System.out.println(userDetails.get("email"));
        System.out.println(userDetails.get("given_name"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently using Keycloak authentication server and accessing currently logged-in user data is accessible like this

```java
String userID;

KeycloakPrincipal kcPrincipal = getPrincipal();
KeycloakSecurityContext ksContext = kcPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
IDToken idToken = ksContext.getToken();
userID = idToken.getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Im using spring boot 2.0 with OAuth so I'm doing it like this

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Object pricipal = auth.getPrincipal();
String user="";
if (pricipal instanceof DefaultOidcUser) {
       user = ((DefaultOidcUser) pricipal).getName();
}
```

Comment: How I can get getName and getAttribute in JSP?

Answer (score -10):

You can find the currently logged in user name without using any spring Security features.
All you need is a jdk 1.8

Do the following :

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
@Override
public ModelAndView AuthChecker(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password, Customers cust) {

     ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
     if((repo.findByEmail(email)!=null) && (repo.findByPassword(password)!=null)) {
        
         
      List<Customers> l=  repo.findAll();
      
      cust = (Customers) l.stream() 
      .filter(x -> email.equals(x.getEmail()))        
      .findAny()                                      
      .orElse(null); 
    
        mv.addObject("user",cust.getName());
         mv.setViewName("DashBoardRedirect");
    
         return mv;
```

Once name fetched successfully, you can use the same in any jsp/thymeleaf view.