# Spring Boot/ Spring Security, login form, password checking

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem with something that is probably very easy, but I don't understand that.

I am not very familiar with Spring Boot, many things happen here automatically. I want to check if someone who write username and password in form is present in database [and his account is activated]. User data is stored in MySQL database configured in application.properties. I want to check if someone with provided username is present in "user" table and check if provided password is equal to user password in database. At the moment I can type any username from database and password can be random (it's obvious to me, because I don't check it anywhere, and weird, because I feel like everything around says it works properly). This sounds so simple to me, but I can't find any proper solution on StackOverflow or tutorials.

My general question is - where and how should I check the password from the login form? Is it done automatically (but it doesn't work somehow), or should I write my custom **controller**/service/method to do that? If custom controller is needed, then what should be my direction to solve my problem?

At the moment I have no idea where to go. I hope all remaining code related to my problem is pasted here. Thank you in advance for all tips and comments about that.

### Code:

ApplicationSecurityAdapter class:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class ApplicationSecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/activation-send").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/reset-password").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/reset-password-change").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/autologin").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/user/delete").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll() // added permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe().key(applicationSecret)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(31536000);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

UserService class:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Value("${app.user.verification}") // set to YES
    private Boolean requireActivation;

    @Value("${app.secret}") // some random stuff
    private String applicationSecret;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    private HttpSession httpSession;

    public final String CURRENT_USER_KEY = "CURRENT_USER";

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = repo.findOneByUserName(username);

        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        if(requireActivation && !user.getToken().equals("1")) {
            Application.log.error("User [" + username + "] tried to log in, but his account is not activated.");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " did not activate his account.");
        }
        httpSession.setAttribute(CURRENT_USER_KEY, user);
        List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(user.getRole());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), auth);
    }
}
```

UserController:

```
@Controller
// @RequestMapping("/user/*")
public class UserController {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Value("${app.user.verification}") // YES
    private Boolean requireActivation;

    @Value("users/")
    private String userRoot;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(User user) {
        return "user/login";
    }
}
```

Login form:

```
<div layout:fragment="content">

    <form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">LOGIN PANEL</h2>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${param.error}">
            Incorrect credentials or account not activated.
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name="username" class="form-control top" placeholder="username goes here..." required="required" autofocus="autofocus"/>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control bottom" placeholder="password goes here..."
           required="required"/>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me"/> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your `loadUserByUsername`

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = repo.findOneByUserName(username);

    if(user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
    if(requireActivation && !user.getToken().equals("1")) {
        Application.log.error("User [" + username + "] tried to log in, but his account is not activated.");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " did not activate his account.");
    }
    httpSession.setAttribute(CURRENT_USER_KEY, user);
    List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(user.getRole());

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), auth);
}
```

You set the user to the session. **Don't do this!** Just load the user and return it. 
The user is stored in the session automatically and can be looked up like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31160173/2576531).
I think the reason why the password check doesn't work is that you configured `BCryptPasswordEncoder` as password encoder.
Be sure, that the password, you have stored in your `User`, is encoded by this encoder.
Otherwise the password check will fail.
To avoid the custom activation checking make your `User` class implement [UserDetails](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html). If you check the docs there are 4 flags you can set, which will be checked by spring boot.

```
boolean isAccountNonExpired() // Indicates whether the user's account has expired.
boolean isAccountNonLocked() // Indicates whether the user is locked or unlocked.
boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() // Indicates whether the user's credentials (password) has expired.
boolean isEnabled() // Indicates whether the user is enabled or disabled.
```

Your implementation of `loadUserByUsername` should look something like this. It really should only do what the method name suggests. Lookup the user and throw a `UsernameNotFoundException` if you cant find a user with the given username.

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
  User user = repo.findOneByUserName(username);

  if(user == null) {
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
  }

  return user;
}
```

If you don't want to make your 'User' implement 'UserDetails' (to separate the framework and your business logic for example) return the Spring [User](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) using [this constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html#User-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-java.util.Collection-), where you can set these flags.
Your implementation could look like this:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
  User user = repo.findOneByUserName(username);

  if(user == null) {
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
  }

  List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(user.getRole());
  return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
    user.getUserName(),
    user.getPassword(),
    requireActivation && !user.getToken().equals("1"), // enabled. Use whatever condition you like
    true, // accountNonExpired. Use whatever condition you like
    true, // credentialsNonExpired. Use whatever condition you like
    true, // accountNonLocked. Use whatever condition you like
    auth);
}
```

The password, authorities, activation state and so on are then checked by spring automatically.

Comment: Setting user to session was not a good idea, so I left loadUserByUsername method like your last code block (as my 'User' is not implementing 'UserDetails'). Luckily, encoding works properly. I need to work with proper views mapping, but it's not related to this question. Thank you for your help!