# How do i save the preloaded data back to my db in another table

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am having the logged user name displayed in my thyme-leaf page and now i would like to save the name in my db together with the filled form

```
<div sec:authorize="is Authenticated()">
<span sec:authentication="name" class="form-control"> </span>                                       </div>
```

that how am fetching the logged user from db .....now how can i make the same name saved in any table i want within a form with other fields that are currently being saved,,,,how do i capture the displayed name?

Answer (score 0):

You should be finding the currently logged in user. You can do that in your controller then pass this information to your Service and Repository layers respectively. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159075/how-to-find-out-the-currently-logged-in-user-in-spring-boot) for a good SO Q&A.  Here is the quick solution:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String userName = auth.getPrincipal();
```

Comment: thanks for respond but you didnt get my question.....okay now that i have the name in the UI how do i save it as i save my other fields in my form

Comment: You dont need to get it from the UI, as my answer states you should be getting the current user from the Spring Security Context.